# String.replaceAll using regular expression in both parameters in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace all instances of a substring with a modified version of the substring, can I do something like:

```js
    const regex = /[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{3}/g; // format: 0000ABC
    myString = myString.replaceAll(regex, regex + " I'm modified");
```

#### Abstract example

If myString is

> 5000ABC, 250XYZ, GEN3000

and I want to modify certain 4 digit - 3 letter patterns, my expected output is

> 5000ABC I'm modified, 250XYZ, 1000DEF I'm modified, GEN3000

Comment: Why not `myString.replaceAll(regex, "$& I'm modified")`

Comment: What exactly is the output you expect?

Comment: @epascarello have updated question for abstract example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand the output format you want, but guessing from your example it looks like you want to append some string after each match. Here we go:

```js
const input = 'Some text with 1234ABC and 5678XYZ';
const regex = /([0-9]{4}[A-Z]{3})/g; // format: 0000ABC
var result = input.replace(regex, "$1 I'm modified");
console.log('input:  ' + input);
console.log('result: ' + result);
```

Output:

```
input:  Some text with 1234ABC and 5678XYZ
result: Some text with 1234ABC I'm modified and 5678XYZ I'm modified
```

Explanation:

- capture your pattern with parenthesis for later use
- use a string `.replace()` where you can reference the captured pattern with `$1`, and prefix/append any text you want

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I have at the moment is

```
const regex = /[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{3}/g;
var matches = myString.match(regex);
if (matches && matches.length > 0) {
   for (var match of matches) {
      var modified = match + "I'm modified";
      myString = myString.replaceAll(match, modified)
   }
}
```